# Finding a user's location without using geolocation in IE 9+

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer, geolocation

I am having trouble with IE9+ incorrectly guessing my location, its over 100 miles wrong.

Found this while doing some research:
[Why is IE9 geolocation support broken compared to other browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079236/why-is-ie9-geolocation-support-broken-compared-to-other-browsers)

It explains my problem and sums up why this works so bad in IE9+. So I need to find a special solution for finding one's location in IE, and use geolocation in other modern browsers. I guess there is no polyfill to fix this issue in IE, or is there?

What other methods is there I can use to find a users location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem was using an free IP-location service, http://freegeoip.net/.

1. Check if the user is using Internet Explorer using Javascript.
2. If true, make an GET request towards "http://freegeoip.net/json", to get the users latitude and longitude depending on the users IP-adress.
3. Call and initiate Google Maps etc.
4. Solution complete.

Its not an amazing solution, but it works and is a decent wordaround.